# Possible Improvements for String Validator?

Tags: java, sql, jsf, validation

I've made this Java method which is used to validate Strings insert into form fields:

```
public void validateDatacenterName(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
                         Object value) throws ValidatorException, SQLException {
  String l;
  String s = value.toString().trim();

  if (s.length() > 18) {
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  Value is too long! (18 digits max)", null));  
  }

  try {
    // l = Long.parseLong(s);
    // if (l > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    // {
    //   throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
    //                    "  '" + l + "' is too large!", null));  
    // }
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { 
    l = null; 
  }

  if (s != null) {
    if (ds == null) 
      throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs;
    int cnt = 0;
    try {
      conn = ds.getConnection();
      ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT count(1) from COMPONENTSTATS where COMPONENTSTATSID = ?");
      ps.setString(1, s);
      rs = ps.executeQuery();

      while(rs.next()) 
        cnt = rs.getInt(1);

      if (cnt > 0) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  '" + s + "' is already in use!", null));                    
      }

    } catch(SQLException x) {
      throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        "  SQL error!", null));                
    } finally {
      if (ps != null) 
        ps.close();
      if (conn != null) 
        conn.close();
    }                      
  } else {
    throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        s.isEmpty() ? "  This field cannot be empty!" : "  '" + s + "' is not a valid name!", null));         
  }

}
```

How I can improve this code? Are there any additional checks I can add in order to improve the form validator?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place for code review. Code reviews belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

- StackOverflow readers will have no idea from your description what is a valid data center name, because we don't know your application.  Is the only requirement that it's numeric?
- If the value is supposed to be numeric, why do you comment out the code that calls `parseLong()`?
- Checking COMPONENTSTATS for the value already in use creates a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).  That is, even after that check, some other application thread could insert the same value before you get to insert it.  Why not enforce uniqueness in the database with a `UNIQUE` constraint?
- How can you call `s.isEmpty()` in your `else` block, when you know `s == null`?
- If this method is part of a class that implements javax.faces.validator.Validator, shouldn't the method be named `validate()`?

Answer (score 2):

You should only use regular expressions if you *really need to*. With the current validation that you are using, the standard `String` methods will suffice.

As much as possible you should aim to keep the method for validation related tasks. To this end, you should extract out the database call into a separate method.

Also you have a `NullPointerException` waiting to happen here:

```
throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                        s.isEmpty() ? "  This field cannot be empty!" : "  '" + s + "' is not a valid name!", null));
```

At this point `s` will be `null` and `NullPointerException` will be thrown before you can throw your `ValidatorException`.

Comment: If `s` was `null`, it would have thrown a `NullPointerException` at `String s = value.toString().trim();` or `if (s.length() > 18) {`.  Don't think it would ever make it to that `s.isEmpty()` where is would also have to be `null`. Good catch on that bad logic though =)

Comment: Any code example of your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would validate with regexp.

unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to give the exact string, but  I am sure who is using daily it will no it in 3 seconds :) I know that would be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Either **I would search the web for a already implemented validation**, or I would make a list of characters, which I want to allow for the String and than check the input e.g. with a regexp that the input does not contain any other characters.

Answer (score 1):

Before `if (s.length() > 18)` check I think You should check s for null

```
if (s !=null && s.length() > 18)
```

And also better to have empty check for string `s.isEmpty()`

Comment: `.isEmpty()` is available since java 1.6 (so not an option for everyone)

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Use `Regex` to validate the `Stirng`'s structure by defining a group of allowed characters and/or symbols
2. Move your null checking logic before `if(s.length() > 18)`. If `s` is `null` that clause will result in a `NullPointerException`.
3. Fix your null check: `if (s != null)` will allow `s = ""` because it's not null, breaking your else statement where you try to validate an empty string (which will result in a `NullPointerException` when you create your validation message). Either use `if(s != null && !s.isEmpty())` or split that validation in two if you want to execute different logic in both cases.